# will round to less digits accelerate computing

Tags: java, performance, double

I am writing a Java program that involves significant computing of double scores. It is very slow now.

If I round to less digits such as 0.54583574982374592 to 0.5458. Will this accelerate my program?

Comment: Nope.  Your computer has hardware designed to run on `double` values with that exact amount of precision; it's not going to run any faster on other `double` values.

Comment: No. But You can use `float`. Unlike `double`, which is 64 bit, `float` is 32 bit and may be faster.

Comment: If you are actually using `double` arithmetic is unlikely to be the performance issue. It is more likely to boxing/unboxing (if you convert to Double) or memory access patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in decimal. The number of decimal digits after the point is a really bad indicator of the "complexity" of the number. For example 0.1 is an infinite fraction in binary, setting plenty of bits. Rounding in binary has some effect, but only on division and square root ([source](http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/GenuineIntel00306C3_Haswell_InstLatX64.txt), and personal experiments) - the common operations (add, multiply, compare) do not depend on the value of the operands in that way (subnormals are often slow, depending on the operation and µarch).

Comment: Thanks! Sorry just after I posted the question, I started to realize that it wont influence cause all of it is in bits. I guess I need to find other reasons for the poor performance.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **no**

`double` does not have a variable precision that would influence the speed of its operations.